# What's the name of this font?

Tags: fonts, font-identification, logo

I need to rebuild this logo for a poster, because it is in poor resolution and all the rest are vector graphics. I am struggling to find the name of the font that was used in the creation of this logo. I have tried several online font recognition tools, but they did not return any satisfactory results. I tried:

- WhatTheFont
- Identifont

and here's the actual logo:

[image: Logo]

Any Ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Neither Identifont nor WhatTheFont produce the right result. Tip: Actually say which you have tried.

Comment: @AndrewLeach thanks for the effort and the suggestion! In the meanwhile, a guy on Typophile found it.

Answer (score 4):

I also posted this [request on Typophile](http://typophile.com/node/108174) and the developer of "Find My Font" actually found it with his software. It's called **[Champagne & Limousines](http://www.dafont.com/champagne-limousines.font)**.